# ruby rails functional test problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I'm getting the following problem with my functional test.

mrbernz:mylife bernardleung$ ruby test/functional/forums_controller_test.rb 
.....

1) Error:
test_should_create_forum(ForumsControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::BadFieldError: Unknown column 'id:3 name' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `roles` (`id`, `id:3 name`) VALUES (707834473, 'Moderator')

A stack trace of the error points as follows...

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in`require_or_load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_on'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in`require_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:853:in `try_to_load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:868:in`require_fixture_classes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:865:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:865:in`require_fixture_classes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:848:in `fixtures'
./test/functional/../test_helper.rb:35
test/functional/forums_controller_test.rb:1:in`require'
test/functional/forums_controller_test.rb:1
Unable to load roles_user, underlying cause no such file to load -- roles_user

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in`require_or_load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_on'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in`require_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:853:in `try_to_load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:868:in`require_fixture_classes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:865:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:865:in`require_fixture_classes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:848:in `fixtures'
test/functional/forums_controller_test.rb:4

My forums_controller_test.rb looks as follows (first few lines anyway)

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

class ForumsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :forums, :users, :roles, :roles_users

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:forums)
  end
```

I don't understand why it's complaining about 'roles_user' as I don't ask for it anywhere, and what I do ask for or declare is 'roles_users' which is a table I do have!

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_mylife_test |
+-----------------------+
| articles              |
| categories            |
| forums                |
| pages                 |
| posts                 |
| roles                 |
| roles_users           |
| schema_migrations     |
| topics                |
| users                 |
+-----------------------+
10 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

help?!

Comment: May be something wrong with your fixtures?

Comment: Do you have a fixture that refers to `roles_user`?

Comment: No I don't have anything within my fixtures that refers to roles_user! I did a search on my entire project and there is no reference to roles_user anywhere other then in my error logs!

Comment: do you have something in your routes like `map.resources :role_user`

Comment: My routes look like this for roles and users. 
  map.resources :roles
  map.resources :users, :member => { :enable => :put } do |users|
    users.resources :roles
  end

As for missing a migration, my db's look fine as per the list so I'm a bit confused... I'm also confused as my manual testing works just my automated functional tests dont...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove :roles_users from the fixtures declaration in ForumsControllerTest.
By specifying :roles_users as a fixture it is trying to load a model called RolesUser. I'm assuming it is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` join table.

Make sure your `users.yml` fixture has:

```
user:
 roles: moderator
```

and your roles.yml fixture has:

```
moderator:
 name: 'Moderator'
```

and that `id` values *are not* set in the `user.yml`  or `roles.yml` files.